# Margin of error for imbalanced discrete set

Tags: classification, statistics, model-evaluations

I'm evaluating the performance of a classifier regarding its false negatives. The classifier performed over 9090 samples, from which 9000 were labeled as negative. I randomly chose 800 samples (out of the 9000) and found that 4 were wrong. This means a 0.5% false negative rate. I also know that the precision (in all the 90 samples labeled positive) is 10%. I want to answer questions like:

- What's the probability that the false negative rate in all the 9000 labeled negative samples is greater than 2%?
- What's the margin of error for a 95% confidence?

Comment: by "I also know that the false positive rate (in all the 90 samples labeled positive) is 10%", do you mean that your `precision` is `90%`? Because False Positive Rate is defined on total negatives as base and not total positive predictions (90 in your case).

Comment: Yes! I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Same question about "This means a 0.5% false negative rate" :-)